# Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jshell

Tags: java, macos, path, zshrc, jshell

Currently getting an error when I run `jshell` or `jenv shell` on macos monterey.

jshell

```
jshell       
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports jshell.  Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

jenvshell

```
jenv shell
jenv: no shell-specific version configured
```

I have run `jenv enable-plugin export`.  Here is my current set up:

Java Version

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

Jenv Version

```
jenv --version
jenv 0.5.5
```

Jenv Java Versions

```
jenv versions
  system
  1.8
  1.8.0.292
* openjdk64-1.8.0.292 (set by /Users/user/.jenv/version)
```

Jenv Doctor

```
jenv doctor              
[OK]    JAVA_HOME variable probably set by jenv PROMPT
[OK]    Java binaries in path are jenv shims
[OK]    Jenv is correctly loaded
```

which java

```
which java
/Users/user/.jenv/shims/java
```

.zshrc

```
JENV_PATH=/Users/user/.jenv/bin
export PATH=$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_SDK:$JENV_PATH:$PATH
eval "$(jenv init -)"
```

Comment: @user16320675 you are correct.  The solution was to install version 18 and use that.  Please post your comment as a solution and I will mark correct.